# Parameter of constructor from exported class has or is using private name '' (empty string) ts(4063)

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement a class in TypeScript that I can optionally pass a variable (`converters`) in the constructor to, that will define the type of a `Generic` that is defined in that class.

In the file below you can see I am importing and exporting a type from another class, I am creating a `Record` from that type called `Converters` and I am creating the types `Names` and `Value` of which the type is defined based on whether or not the generic passed to it (passed to the class in the implementation) and is of the type `Converters`.

So whether or not the class `Service` receives `converters` as a parameter the `Names<C>` and `Value<C, N>` will return different types.

```
/**
 * importing and exporting some types
 **/

import { Converter } from "./characteristic";
export { Converter } from "./characteristic";

/**
 * defining some types myself
 **/

export type Converters = Record<string, Converter<any>>;

export type Names<C> = C extends Converters ? keyof C : (string | number);

export type Value<C, N extends Names<C>> = C extends Converters
  ? ConvertersValue<C, N>
  : Buffer;

export type ConvertersValue<
  C extends Converters,
  N extends Names<C>
> = C[N] extends Converter<infer V> ? V : never;

/**
 * implementation
 **/

export default class Service<C> {
  private converters?: Converters;

  constructor(converters?: C extends Converters) {
  //                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
  //                                 an error occurs here
    this.converters = converters;
  }

  public async read<N extends Names<C>>(name: N): Promise<Value<C, N>> {
    throw new Error("Not implemented yet");
  }
}
```

This works great. But I want to `TypeGuard` the parameter that can be passed to the constructor so I can make sure users can pass nothing (`undefined`) to it, but if the pass something to it it must of the the type `Converters`. So I wrote

```
constructor(converters?: C extends Converters) {}
```

But this throws a Typescript

> ```
> type Converters = {
>     [x: string]: Converter<any>;
> }
> Parameter 'converters' of constructor from exported class has or is using private name ''.ts(4063)
> Parameter 'converters' of constructor from exported class has or is using private name ''.ts(4063)
> ```

I am exporting all of the types that I am using and TypeScript hits me that an empty string is missing so I am not sure what is wrong.

*edit, weirdly, this also happens when I use this as a contructor*

```
  constructor(converters: C extends string) {
    this.converters = converters;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post a playground or other web ide link that reproduces this error?  Or otherwise make this a [mcve]?  That error message `has or is using private name ''` sure sounds like a compiler bug, but I wouldn't want to file an issue until I could reproduce it.

Comment: Hey thanks again @jcalz ! I will do that, but after some more debugging, I figured my question will have to be "how to I typeguard a generic and also make it optional", I will edit my question accordingly. I'm so sorry for bugging with these stupid incomplete questions.

Comment: Hey, that problem was that you cannot do `something extends something` `constructor(converters?: C extends Converters)` in  that signature call, but this is what I actually wanted to achieve and got solved (with playground this time) https://stackoverflow.com/q/57889154/1183252 Thanks a bunch though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else finding this, declare the generic before using it in the function signature, eg.

`constructor<C extends string>(converters?:C) { .... }`

not

`constructor(converters?:C extends string) { .... }`

I'm using it in an interface declaration:

```
interface Foo {
    myMethod<T extends MyAbstractClass>(obj:T):void;
}
```

Comment: This leads to "TS1092: Type parameters cannot appear on a constructor declaration."

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to have been that extending the generic in the constructor wasn't possible

```
constructor(converters?: C extends Converters)
```

The same way I could not do

```
constructor(converters: C extends string)
```