# Type guarding a generic and defining it as optional

Tags: typescript

I have a class that accepts a generic

```
interface Converter<T = Buffer> {
  uuid: string;
  decode?: (value: Buffer) => T;
  encode?: (value: T) => Buffer;
}

type Converters = Record<string, Converter<any>>;

export default class Service<C extends Converters> {
  private converters?: Converters;

  constructor(converters?: C) {
    this.converters = converters;
  }
}
```

The idea is that using the constructor, any type of `Converter<T>` can be used with the `Service` class. So I could do this:

```
// Converters using Converter<string>
const converters = {
  manufacturer: {
    uuid: "2a29",
    decode: (buffer: Buffer) => buffer.toString()
  },
}

const service = new Service(converters);
```

this

```
// Converters using Converter<number>
const converters = {
  model: {
    uuid: "2a24",
    decode: (buffer: Buffer) => buffer.readInt8(0)
  }
}

const service = new Service(converters);
```

this

```
// Converters using Converter<string> and Converter<number>
const converters = {
  manufacturer: {
    uuid: "2a29",
    decode: (buffer: Buffer) => buffer.toString()
  },
  model: {
    uuid: "2a24",
    decode: (buffer: Buffer) => buffer.readInt8(0)
  }
}

const service = new Service(converters);
```

or simply this

```
const service = new Service();
```

because converters is optional.

Now the issue here is that the `Service` class has a method called `read` that will accept a parameter called `name` and return a value and that the type of `name` and the return type should be based on

- which converters have been passed to the `Service` class
- if any converters have been passed to the `Service` class at all

if converters have been provided

- read should only accept keys of the converters as a `name` parameter
- read should return the type of the generic of a converter corresponding to that name

if no converters have been passed, `read` should accept any string as parameter and return a Buffer

So if I pass

```
const converters = {
  manufacturer: {
    uuid: "2a29",
    decode: (buffer: Buffer) => buffer.toString()
  },
  model: {
    uuid: "2a24",
    decode: (buffer: Buffer) => buffer.readInt8(0)
  }
}

const service = new Service(converters);
const serviceNoConverter = new Service();
```

This should happen

```
const value = service.read("manufacturer");
//    ^^^^^ type string

const value = service.read("model");
//    ^^^^^ type number

const value = service.read("aassd");
//                          ^^^^^ type error, not manufacturer or model

const value = serviceNoConverter.read("asdasdasd")
//    ^^^^^ type Buffer                ^^^^^^^^^ any string is allowed
```

So with the help from StackOverflow (especially from jcalz, thanks buddy) I got so far as to do this:

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFcY2sg3gWAChkTkwB7AZTClAHMAuZACgEpkBeAPmQGcb6RUsigQ4AEwCS4ABxNm5LLwhgmIdAFsARtHbdk67dCIBfIkVCRYiFAGFyIAG7QrAHgAqnNJmxQeBYmR0dGBxJn5aEDoAbiFkcQgEcgSAfnlHOAAbdAgmDCxdTh53WMCIECTU9Kycpnc9HnzfUrNCIjAATwAHOwdnKCteLwAlRPIocVcI+gAaZHsnF2hXOBAOri5S9u6UADk4DQhXWx4OeeQIAA9IEHEhhf7B5BTkAGsIDsVz8IEorcIrl1xmAyDtkAA1GpHWxzXYXa7lO7IfaHY4bLy2eE3JEPJZQXhxF64gbQXiQ7LQ2FcOJ5HzQf6A4GgnrzPp4slQ1xxTFXbH3Nkk-FzOJw3mIoYo6HUwineYAbV2AF0seLWYtBa5QL4ITwXuDkGoIP1-kQEJk4LwhpRoI5gEg0Xg4l1aBlIMgkurBmk1Y9Sf8SB6IugEBQoMwPb78d7bOwAsIwAALYC8AB0EfZXnTgt4pRIrSd6C0mTtIjEk1FCNuEoOUq4zBANaYu1YTHJOWOVMdgWEwBgLETybTAsGsbiwnjCag5AA7gYILOAKJQKdhgBEIHIIOAGi6mQgh3AEHEyFAZCTQ13cA6dCn6Fuq9YufHJgumWUXfH48TU9nIHnyCXFdmHXTcTx3PcD0gY9TwHC9zWvW970fMdSFaPNTHMQhAxBLMnjOONkA0VZMEQMB0FEKAmAIkhglCJhVwAJjgBiAE5VxmFCEkqXIWC0OlKO8AooAaZA+KElMKGoSI6DYOITA4wINGSCBMiolDaLCZBGOYgAWdjOLGBJ5DE3xaSEkSTOgFNRAkaQwBkZgAAZWDkjC2iwhx+D4G07RQM4-1na0oFtJA2FKbDvOC3yAHVgETYlSS8ALkCCkKIHDYdSRc9yIoyCkvGUKKkGsstgItcQJAfcLPJBPKcgAMSnDRiSsAqfKQWL4oFUkSokYCiPUeAQ3I6AqtNGrkDqiAGMa8hmsyqA2qKiBOoTBL8V68R+uUzIqqAA)

everything here works exactly as described, **but**, you can see that at

```
constructor(converters?: C) {
  this.converters = converters;
}
```

there is an error where `converters` does not match `this.converters` because `converters` is not type-guarded while `this.converters` is of the type `Converters`. But I can't type-guard the generic as

```
Service<C extends Converters>
```

because that will break the functionality of `read` as described.

So my question is how can I type-guard the parameter while still keeping this functionality and making it optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think constraining `C` as `Converters | undefined` and `undefined` as the default value should work. I would also suggest to change the member variable to be of type `C`, now that it is properly constrained:

```js
class Service<C extends Converters | undefined = undefined> {
   private converters?: C;

   constructor(converters?: C) {
     this.converters = converters;
   }
   //...
}
```

The key here is that by setting the default to `undefined`, creating a service without converters will result in the type: `Service<undefined>` instead of `Service<Record<...> | undefined>`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFcY2sg3gWAChkTkwB7AZTClAHMAuZACgEpkBeAPmQGcb6RUsigQ4AEwCS4ABxNm5LLwhgmIdAFsARtHbdk67dCIBfIkVCRYiFAGFyIAG7QrAHgAqnNJmxQeBYmR0dGBxJn5aEDoAbiFkcQgEcgSAfnlHOAAbdAgmDCxdTh53WMCIECTU9Kycpnc9HnzfUrNCIjAATwAHOwdnKCteLwAlRPIocVcI+gAaZHsnF2hXOBAOri5S9u6UADk4DQhXWx4OeeQIAA9IEHEhhf7B5BTkAGsIDsVz8IEorcIrl1xmAyDtkAA1GpHWxzXYXa7lO7IfaHY4bLy2eE3JEPJZQXhxF64gbQXiQ7LQ2FcOJ5HzQf6A4GgnrzPp4slQ1xxTFXbH3Nkk-FzOJw3mIoYo6HUwineYAbV2AF0seLWYtBa5QL4ITwXuDkGoIP1-kQEJk4LwhpRoI5gEhjirbvz1U8AD5BW4QGCgCDiLzoT3ekC+-xxLq0DKQZBJF2ktLzf4kGMRdAIChQZgxx5xpi2dgBYRgAAWwF4ADos+yvJXBbxSiRWmH0FpMnaRGJJqKEU7kQcpVxmCA+0xdqwmOScscqXg4sJgDAWMXSxWBYN87PhKRi1ByAB3AwQfcAUSgO4zACIQOQQcANF1MhBDuBfchQGQS0N73AOnQdwHxOerD1puJgXJkygzoEm5bkWO77sGx6nuMzCXter53g+T6QH6b5Lp+5o-n+tyAcBwitA2pjmIQyYgjWTxnAWyAaKsmCIGA6CiFATCMSQwShEw54AExwIJACc54zBuCSVLkLBaHSXHeAUUANMg8nKWWFDUJEdBsHEJiSYEGjJBAmTcRufFhMgQkiQALBJUljAk8jqb4tLKaprnQGWogSNIYAyMwAAMrD6ZRbTUQ4-B8DadooGcCHINaUC2kgbClDRMUpXFADqwDFsSpJeIlyWpRAmarqSoURZlGQUl4yjZUgPkdihFriBIJGmlFIJ1TkABiO4aMSVgNbFSB5QVAqki1Egocx6jwGmHHQF1kUgNFfUQIJg3kMNlVQGNTUQJNRaFfis3iPNJmZCRQA)

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFcY2sg3gWAChkTkwB7AZTClAHMAuZACgEpkBeAPmQGcb6RUsigQ4AEwCS4ABxNm5LLwhgmIdAFsARtHbdk67dCIBfIkVCRYiFAGFyIAG7QrAHgAqnNJmxQeBYmR0dGBxJn5aEDoAbiFkcQgEcgSAfnlHOAAbdAgmDCxdTh53WMCIECTU9Kycpnc9HnzfUrNCIjAATwAHOwdnKCteLwAlRPIocVcI+gAaZHsnF2hXOBAOri5SogRMuF4hymhHYCRXW2QIAA9IEHEhhf7B-ziu2gzIZCTFgeheNPmtoEvhF0AgKFBmF9Hr9-rZ2AFhGAABbAXgAOihSygQw4nz6WN4pRIrRe6C0mROIjEkwAchdruU7sgANYQDqKeZcZggOAaXLIGnwuLCYAwFjI1EY-E-bFCwLCEiiMDoKAgMgo9GYmW8ADaPL5AF0iQqTBdMso8MKFcioOQAO4GCAOgCiUFtEIARCByGBkMANF1MhA+eAIOI-WqJUNA3AOnRbehbh7WMbhK1iaZzIRgb6tYMvAjkBpVphEMrRFAmIWSMFQkwPQAmOANgCcHpmVoSlX5zC0PmgeX7UAayD7BSgaIo1EidDYcRMHcCGmSEEyVattbCyEbzYALO3O2MEvIx75B+OR6foGjRBJpGAZMwAAyseeZtrZhz8PhHE4oXEgE6yCHFAxxIGwpQ5j+oF-gA6sAyIPNAvxeIBDogWBECQtKgyvh+UEZNkEAAKogMy3p2mquLKDBSA3tSzAens4gSMmkFfr6hE5AAYraGhITKXg0Zh8GIdKvz0RIjHFuo8Bgiq0BsdsHHIFxEANrx5D8ThODUb+SCiUiAkSbe4jSSumRsUAA).

The initial problems in the playground were:
 - Overcomplication.
 - `converters` property type.

As **lukasgeiter** noted, `converters` should be of type C.
However, the default generic value of `undefined` is not necessary.
It works perfectly fine like this too:

```
...
class Service<C extends Converters> {
  private converters?: C;

  constructor(converters?: C) {
    this.converters = converters;
  }

  public read<N extends keyof C>(name: N): C[N] {
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Alexey, thank you, But if you do it that way, you will get any as a return type when no converters have been passed to the service